# Compile NPM package with Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, es6-modules

I need to use the functionality of an NPM package ([fit-file-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fit-file-parser)) in a non-Node app. So far, I've tried

1. Pull down the package, build it, and include the output bundle as a script tag. The problem here is that the built package `dist/` includes 4 files, each of which is using modules via `require()`. Mostly, they depend on one another so I thought I could just include them in the correct order, but one depends on `buffer`.

```
binary.js
fit-parser.js
fit.js
messages.js
```

2. Run the `dist/` directory through Browserify to produce a `package.bundle.js` file and include *that* as a script tag. This seems to run without error, but the main function I need to instantiate the logic I need isn't present in the browser. Actually, *none* of the globals present when running the files directly are present after including the bundle file.

```
browserify fit-parser.js -o fit-parser.bundle.js
```

To use this package, one needs to be able to instantiate a new `FitParser` using `new FitParser({...options})`. This function comes from the `fit-parser` file, but I can't seem to get it into the global scope of the browser.

Comment: Try adding -> `--standalone FitParser`

Comment: This look like it worked! So glad it was a config flag and not something like "well, edit all the files to ....". If you make an answer out of it with an explanation of _why_ it worked, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NPM packages are generally modules, as such they don't normally effect the global.

Normally you would be doing something like ->

```
const FitParser = require("fit-parser");
```

or

```
import {FitParser} from "fit-parser"
```

The second option is now supported in modern browsers, so in theory you could use that option and not use browserfy.

But if you want to use the old fashioned way, with a global.  This is what `--standalone {exportname}` option is used for.  `{exportname}` been what you want to call it on the global.  Basically it's kind of doing a `window.FitParser = FitParser` inside the script.